# Track user behaviour outside of my app/domain

Tags: javascript, cookies, web, user-activity

Rigth now i know about mixpanel, and it's a really great to track/send user activity, but we would also like to track his activity outside of our application. Mainly, what other pages and sections of that pages that he visits.

For example, after user went out of our page, hi visited:

http://www.google.com

http://www.dell.com

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed

etc, etc,

Someone told me that i could track that via cookies, but the cookies only store plain text, i don't know how can i get from a cookie what the user did.

If you could put me in the right path either with a tutorial or a heads up on what should be used.

Comment: no, you can not track a user like that without their express permission, don't even try write anything that will attempt to do so, just forget users that do not go to your little corner of the web

Comment: this article helped me to explain a little bit how it can be done. Apparently i need something related to my site, that could look for the cookie with the user id and then do whatever i wanted to do http://www.geek.com/news/facebook-explains-why-it-tracks-you-even-when-youre-logged-out-1424083/